# magento 2.1.7 how to access from another device on localhost?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, development, localhost, access

magento 2.1.7 how to access from another device on localhost?
I can access to phpmyadmin, but when I tried to access magento/admin from another device browser jumps to localhost instead of my typed IP address.
How can i give permission to access from another device?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have changed the base url

You can change it from the database refer `core_config_data`

change url for `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url`

from

```
http://localhost/your/magento/path/
```

to

```
http://10.0.0.1/your/magento/path/
```

where `10.0.0.1` is my lan IP